# Hive join tables and keep only 1 column

Tags: sql, hadoop, join, hive, hiveql

I have below table join and noticed that Hive keeps two copies of the pk column - one from table b and one from table c. Is there a way to keep only 1 of those columns?

I can always replace `select *` with exact `select column1, column2` etc but that wont be too efficient

```
with a as (
select 
*
from table1 b left join table2 c 
on b.pk = c.pk

)
select 
*
from a;

;
```

#update 1

is it possible to alias many columns?
for example the below line works

`select b.pk as duplicate_pk`

but is there a way to do something like
`select b.* as table2` to add text `table2` before all the columns of the table b?

Comment: Your only option is to list all the fields out. Otherwise, to "select all, and one specific", you'll get that individual column 3 times. There's no operation for all except one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already tried this but you can choose what to select using either

b.* to select cols of only table1

c.* to select cols of only table2

Example:

```
with a as (
select 
b.*
from table1 b left join table2 c 
on b.pk = c.pk
)
select 
*
from a;
```

Comment: this wont work because i want all the columns from both tables and want to keep only 1 copy of the column pk